# best practice of disable cpanel from edit apache main conf file

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, cpanel

i have a centos server controlled by cpanel, i have some proxy i want to set for my main domain, my configuration work clearly at /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf, but any edit in cpanel will remove my configuration and regenerate the file again, how to stop cpanel from control apache conf file or is there a best practice for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice, given that you have cpanel installed, is to make any changes you need to make via cpanel. Cpanel is very explicit in its installation instructions that there is no provision for removing it once it is installed, so your choices are either to use cpanel for all your control operations, or wipe your server and reinstall what you want to use without cpanel.